# Android su commands not working when called for modifying /system in android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, root

What i basically have is a simple android navigation drawer with some fragments , i have a checkbox called from a `Fragment` placed in the main activity which then when clicked executes a root command that should modify the build.prop file in /system but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work and i get this in the logs -->

```
D/su      (17546): su invoked.
D/su      (17546): starting daemon client 10129 10129
D/su      (17548): remote pid: 17546
D/su      (17548): remote pts_slave:
D/su      (17548): waiting for child exit
D/su      (17550): su invoked.
D/su      (17550): db allowed
D/su      (17550): 10129 /system/xbin/su executing 0 /system/bin/sh using binary
 /system/bin/sh : sh
D/su      (17548): sending code
D/su      (17548): child exited
D/su      (17546): client exited 0
D/AndroidRuntime(17551):
D/AndroidRuntime(17551): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.Run
timeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(17551): CheckJNI is OFF
D/AndroidRuntime(17551): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
```

here is the code of my `Activity` (`AboutActivity`)

```
package com.adromo.tweaker.activities;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.adromo.tweaker.R;
import com.adromo.tweaker.fragments.InitD;
import com.adromo.tweaker.fragments.StartFragment;
import com.adromo.tweaker.widget.CustomDrawerLayout;
import com.ikimuhendis.ldrawer.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import com.ikimuhendis.ldrawer.DrawerArrowDrawable;

import org.sufficientlysecure.rootcommands.Shell;
import org.sufficientlysecure.rootcommands.command.SimpleCommand;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class AboutActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static Context appContext;

    //==================================
    // Drawer
    //==================================
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CustomDrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerArrowDrawable drawerArrow;
    private boolean drawerArrowColor;

    private static int DRAWER_MODE = 0;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    private static final int MENU_BACK = Menu.FIRST;

    String titleString[];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        appContext = getApplicationContext();

        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

        mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dw_navigation_drawer);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                R.layout.drawer_list,
                android.R.id.text1,
                getTitles()));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

        setUpNavigationDrawer(
                findViewById(R.id.dw_navigation_drawer),
                (CustomDrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dw_drawer_layout));

        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Adromo");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }


        CopyAssets();
    }



    private void CopyAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("Files");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        for(String filename : files) {
            System.out.println("File name => "+filename);
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open("Files/"+filename);   // if files resides inside the "Files" directory itself
                out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Adromo/" + filename );
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, MENU_BACK, 0, R.string.toggle_back_cfibers)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_back)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case MENU_BACK:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    //==================================
    // Methods
    //==================================

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the
     * navigation menu_drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentContainerView The view of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout          The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUpNavigationDrawer(View fragmentContainerView, CustomDrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = fragmentContainerView;
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        drawerArrow = new DrawerArrowDrawable(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean isLayoutRtl() {
                return false;
            }
        };
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                drawerArrow, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

        if (!mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Restores the action bar after closing the menu_drawer
     */
    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setTitle(getTitle());
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.dw_container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(getPosition(position)))
                .commit();
    }

    /**
     * Depending on if the item is shown or not, it increases
     * the position to make the activity load the right fragment.
     *
     * @param pos The selected position
     * @return the modified position
     */
    public int getPosition(int pos) {
        int position = pos;
        switch (DRAWER_MODE) {
            default:
            case 0:
                position = pos;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (pos > 0) position = pos + 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (pos > 3) position = pos + 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (pos > 0) position = pos + 1;
                if (pos > 3) position = pos + 2;
                break;
        }
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of titles for the tabstrip to display depending on if the
     * voltage control fragment and battery fragment will be displayed. (Depends on the result of
     * Helpers.voltageTableExists() & Helpers.showBattery()
     *
     * @return String[] containing titles
     */
    private String[] getTitles() {
        String titleString[];
        DRAWER_MODE = 0;
        titleString = new String[]{
                getString(R.string.start_title),
                getString(R.string.navdraw_initd),};
        return titleString;
    }

    //==================================
    // Internal Classes
    //==================================

    public static final int FRAGMENT_ID_StartFragment = 0;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_ID_InitD = 1;


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static Fragment newInstance(int fragmentId) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (fragmentId) {
                default:
                case FRAGMENT_ID_StartFragment:
                    fragment = new StartFragment();
                    break;
                case FRAGMENT_ID_InitD:
                    fragment = new InitD();
                    break;
            }

            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
            // intentionally left blank
        }
    }

    // begin initd checkboxes

    public void initd1(View view) {
        // Is the view now checked?
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        // Check which checkbox was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.initd1:
                if (checked){

                    try {
                        Shell shell = Shell.startRootShell();
                        SimpleCommand command2 = new SimpleCommand("su -c cp /system/build.prop /system/build.prop.bak");
                        shell.add(command2).waitForFinish();
                        shell.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }  else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOL",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                // Remove the meat
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code of my fragment

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 Carbon Development
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.adromo.tweaker.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.adromo.tweaker.R;

public class InitD extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.initd, container, false);


    }

    }
```

the library i am using is called `rootcommands` (i think this shouldn't matter as every library i try gives me the same exact result)
i am running android lolipop 5.0.1 on an SGS4

Comment: check this link it can help..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293327/android-change-permission-of-system-files

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have mounted /system as read-write.

Run this command for mounting r/w:

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

And for mounting read-only again do:

```
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

Never forget this or you cannot write to /system.