# Android : change permission of system files

Tags: android, file-permissions

My phone is rooted and i wrote code in my app to change file permission of system file which is located at /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness");
```

but this code can't change the file permission of the specified file and i won't got any kind of error or exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the RootTools.jar from this link https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/releases

Put that .jar file into your project's 'libs' directory

```
import com.stericson.RootTools.*;
```

.
.

```
Command cmd=new Command(0,"chmod 766 /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness");
RootShell.getShell(true).add(cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you execute su-ed commands. Please refer to http://su.chainfire.eu/ for guidance.